# Why can you declare an NSInteger with a string value?

Tags: objective-c

Why is it that you can do something like this?

```
NSInteger something = @"something";
```

It feels weird that this doesn't throw an error and instead returns some number that, in fact, is an NSInteger.

Comment: I got this warning: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') with an expression of type 'NSString *'`.

Comment: what code did you use?

Comment: I am using the code you posted. Using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MO365.png

Comment: Weird, mine seems to compile. I'm also on 7.2. The value I get returned is 4298319088

Comment: You are right locoboy, this code will generate warning not error, it will convert the string to its integer equivalent.

Comment: @the_UB how do I prevent it from doing that? Can I create a method around this to check it?

Comment: There is a method: Consider the warning and the suggestion to resolve it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me it says ***Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') with an expression of type 'NSString*** **'*

[image]

***I feel, what you get number is memory address of that NSString.***

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from compiling?

Answer (score 0):

In Languages Like Objective C, When You Define a class or a constant string(What you define like `@"something"` is a constant string), it will be stored somewhere and the pointer to it will be used. Pointers are 32-bit and 64-bit. 32-bit pointers are 32-bit Integers so they can easily be casted to an integer. So there is no way to throw an error as it is a legal assignment.

Answer (score 0):

it's the same line of code

```
  NSInteger something = [@"something" integerValue];
```

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)